# Finding two minimum elements in a linked list

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to work on linked list to enhance my concepts on pointers.

I have successfully created linked list and it also give the minimum two elements but i tried on number of elements to test it.

Suddenly i found that it was not working for the following exmaple:

```
enter the size of node
4
start entering the number of elements until your size
6
1
7
59
Printing linked list
6-> 1-> 7-> 59-> 

 The two minimumnumbers are  min1 :1   and min2 : 1
```

My full code to do so is: **You can directly switch to function find_two_min()**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <malloc.h> 
#include <string.h>

struct node 
{
    int freq;
    struct node * next;
};
typedef struct node node;
node * tree;

//Problem creating area is below (code for finding minimum two elements)
void find_two_min(node**List,node** lmin1,node** lmin2)
{
    node*temp=*List;    
    node*min1,*min2;
    node*var1=*List;
    node* second=(*List)->next;
    if(var1>second)
    {
      min2=var1;
      min1=second;
    }
    else
    {
      min1=var1;
      min2 =second;
    }
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->freq<min2->freq)
        {
            min1=min2;
            min2=temp;    
        }
        else if(temp->freq<min1->freq)
        {
            min1=temp;
        }    
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    *lmin1=min1; 
    *lmin2=min2;
}

void main() 
{
    int size, data;
    node* min1, *min2;
    int count = 0; //this count flag is to check is it's first node or not inside the do-while loop.
    tree = NULL;
    printf("enter the size of node\n");
    scanf("%d", & size);
    printf("start entering the number of elements until your size\n");
    node * prev;
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", & data);
        if (count == 0)
        {
            node * temp;
            temp = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp-> freq = data;
            temp-> next = NULL;
            prev = temp;
            tree=prev;
        } 
        else
        {
            node * temp ;
            temp = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp-> freq = data;
            temp-> next = NULL;
            prev-> next = temp;
            prev=prev->next;
        }
        size--;
        ++count;
    }
    while (size > 0);

    printf("Printing linked list\n");
    node * temp1;
    temp1 = tree;
    while (temp1!= NULL) 
    {
        printf("%d-> ", temp1-> freq);
        temp1 = temp1-> next;
    }
    node*temp5=tree;
    find_two_min(&temp5,&min1,&min2);
   printf("\n The two minimumnumbers are  min1 :%d   and min2 : %d\n",min1->freq,min2->freq);

}
```

**Could any one please let me know why it is not working on this particular example, whereas it was working on other samples? Could you please help me in correcting it ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you arbitrary set at the beginning `min1` as the first element and `min2` as the 2nd element, and then - you start traversing from the first element (`temp`).

This makes you read the first 2 elements twice, and if one of them is the minimum - it is also inserted twice, the algorithm 'thinks' you have two elements with the value 1.

The solution to this problem could be following one of the two approaches:

1. Set `min1` and `min2` to the first elements, after checking which is indeed smaller, and then start traversing only from the 3rd element - avoid re-reading an element you have already read.
2. (better solution) set `min1` and `min2` as values that are larger than the range of the elements. A good choice will be using `INT_MAX` - it will ensure your logic is invoked from the first steps of your algorithm.

Comment: yes you are right, I have changed my code to find min and max among min1 and min2 , But i don't know how to start from the 3rd element since it is a linked list. Could you please give me any algorithm or piece of code to make as reference ? will be a big help thanks

Comment: @user234839 I'd suggest using the 2nd suggestion, and not working from the 3rd element, it will result in a much better code

Comment: sorry i couldn't understand the second answer of yours , Actually i don't know what could be the range of elements in adavance( and i am obliged not to use inbuilt functions, If they are so,because the objective is to develop concepts).could you please still help me ? Thanks

Comment: could you please help me in the first answer you gave ?Thanks

Comment: @user234839 Note that this approach will fail if the list's size is 2 without additional checking.

Comment: @user234839, wrong. `temp` is the first node, `temp->next` is the second, and `temp->next->next` is the third. I'd also advocate using the second suggestion, and definitely pay attention to @amit's warning.

Answer (score 1):

You're starting `temp` at the first node, even though you've already considered both it and the second node in your initialization. Try starting it at the third node instead.

Comment: yes you are right, I have changed my code to find min and max among min1 and min2 , But i don't know how to start from the 3rd element since it is a linked list. Could you please give me any algorithm or piece of code to make as reference ? will be a big help thanks